# Linked In API article thumbnails

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to migrate existing code that fetches organization posts from ugcPosts API to new versioned call of the Posts API(version `202210`) and I'm facing issues with getting thumbnails for articles. Response that I get from Posts API doesn't contain thumbnail URL but instead it contains thumbnail URN(old ugcPost API returned thumbnail URL as a part of the post). Here is an example of an article post that I get from API

```
{
            "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false,
            "createdAt": 1666603988797,
            "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
            "lastModifiedAt": 1666603988797,
            "visibility": "PUBLIC",
            "publishedAt": 1666603988797,
            "author": "urn:li:organization:1111",
            "id": "urn:li:share:2222",
            "distribution": {
                "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
                "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
            },
            "content": {
                "article": {
                    "description": "some description",
                    "thumbnail": "urn:li:image:3333",
                    "source": "https://example.com",
                    "title": "some title"
                }
            },
            "commentary": "some comment",
            "lifecycleStateInfo": {
                "isEditedByAuthor": false
            }
        }
```

I tried to use Images API to fetch thumbnail URL using a call

> GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/images/urn:li:image:3333

Unfortunately Linked In API responds with code 400 and message `Invalid asset owner urn type provided: urn:li:article:4444`

I don't get why it happens. Token that I'm using has enough permissions to fetch organization posts(token's scope contains permissions w_member_social, r_liteprofile, r_1st_connections_size, w_organization_social, r_member_social, r_organization_social, rw_organization_admin). Article id that presents in error message isn't anyhow connected to post id. It's also not clear why that asset is referenced as `urn:li:article` while the post itself is described as `urn:li:share`. To me it looks like Linked In API bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there was a bug in Linked In API which was confirmed by their support. At this moment same calls work fine with version 202210